# Alias between jQuery, BootStrap and Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, prototypejs

I'm using Bootstrap which use jQuery to works, but I'm using Prototype too in the same project. I know that I can change the alias in jQuery but, how can I change the alias in Bootstrap.js for use jQuery and continues using $ in Prototype?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to create a unique jQuery reference and use it instead of `$` sign. Something like this:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

As far as Bootstrap is concerned, you don't have to worry about it. Bootstrap jQuery plugins are properly wrapped into IIFE like `+function($) { ... }(jQuery)` so there will be no issue because `jQuery` is still left unchanged.